# Numpy FFT and MATLAB FFT don't agree

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, fft

I have an array of values like:

```
array([[ 0.87494659],
   [-0.73138314],
   [ 0.87494659],
```

In Matlab I do the fft and normalize:
 `Ifft = fft(arrayvalues,nfft)/nfft;`

output: 
 `-0.0109 + 0.0000i
   0.0141 - 0.0073i
   0.0166 - 0.0010i`

but when I try to do this in numpy:

```
np.fft.fft(arrayvalues)
```

I get output:

```
array([[ 0.87494659+0.j],
   [-0.73138314+0.j],
   [ 0.87494659+0.j],
```

Clearly this is wrong.  I know that the values from MATLAB are correct but I'm not sure why numpy is not giving me the correct values.

Comment: your output is your input. Are you sure you are doing it right? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: How exactly are you calling the numpy version and seeing the output? I have a feeling you're expecting it to work in place, and the initial array is actually modified as a side-effect so you're not seeing the result of the actual calculation.

Comment: In other words, what do you get from `my_result = np.fft.fft(arrayvalues)` then `print(my_result)`?

Comment: I found what the issue was.  I read the values from a csv file into a variable.  I was doing this: arrayvalues=values[:,[0]] but I changed it to arrayvalues=values[:,0] and now it works.  Thanks.

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer and accept it so we can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the issue was. I read the values from a csv file into a variable. I was doing this: arrayvalues=values[:,[0]] but I changed it to arrayvalues=values[:,0] and now it works